# Unexpected token require('https’)?

Tags: node.js, https

I am new to node js. I am a bit struggling to fix this compilation issue.
How do I fix this? I believe I am missing some package. How can I include it?
I get error on the line require('https') i.e unexpected token. I have tried running npm install https -g but it hasn't fixed anything. I am running this code on Ubuntu and OSX.

```
var https = require('https’);
const parseUrl = require('parseurl');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(‘/Users/admin/Dropbox/node_prj/SiteNodeJS/server.key’),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(‘/Users/admin/Dropbox/node_prj/SiteNodeJS/server.crt’)
};



const fileEngine = require('./fileErrHandler');
const UrlLoader = require('./urlController');

https.createServer(options, function (req, res)
{
    try
    {

        // this is a library function
        var pathName = decodeURIComponent(req.url);

        var pathCheck = fileEngine(pathName);       //return true or error message
        if(pathCheck){

        }
        else{

        }


        var fileResEngine=  new fileEngine(pathName);

        // create a literal validateFile to validate the path
        fileResEngine.pathCheck();
        if (fileResEngine.error === true )
        {
            res.statusCode = fileResEngine.statusCode;
            res.end(fileResEngine.ErrorMsg);

            return;
        }

        else
        {
           var UrlResLoader = new UrlLoader();
           UrlResLoader.requestUrl(fileResEngine, function(urctrl){
              res.writeHead(urctrl.httpcode, urctrl.fileType);
              res.write(urctrl.data);
              res.end();
           });
        }

    }
    catch(err)
    {
        res.statusCode = err.status || 500;
        res.end(err.message);
    }

}).listen(443);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a typo here: `var https = require('https’ <---);` You have a tick instead of a single quote.